# Reading collection of user input from the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a page to display list of questions to user & read user input for each question.

Issue: When user submits the Form, `Model` Parameter is null.

Post Action of the View is defined as below -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Question> model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Code to display options to user is as below -

```
@foreach (var quest in Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => quest.Title, quest.Title)
        <ol class="Opt">
            @foreach (var opt in quest.Options)
            {                                    
                <li>@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => opt, opt.Title)
                    @Html.LabelFor(o => opt.Title, opt.Title)                                
                </li>
            }
        </ol>
    </li>
}
```

Here model is `@model List<LakshyaMvc.Models.Question>` and of course I have wrapped the code inside `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your View Model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Queries", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model[i].Question, Model[i].Question)
        <ol class="Opt">
            @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count; j++)
            {                                    
                <li>@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => Model[i].Options[j].Option, false)
                    @Html.LabelFor(o => Model[i].Options[j].Option,
                                                     Model[i].Options[j].Option)
                </li>
            }
        </ol>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    }
}
```